# How to use Python Babel with dynamically constructed string

Tags: python, python-babel

I'm trying to use babel to extract and update a constructed string but I still haven't found a good way to do it (without any hassle)

My current approach to construct the string:

```
def calculate_money(amount):
    (usd, cent) = calculate(amount)

    if not (usd or cent):
        return ''

    params = {}
    result = 'Buying this will cost you '
    if usd:
        result += '%(usd) USD'
        params['usd'] = usd
    if cent:
        if params:
            result += ' and '
        result += '%(cent) cent'
        params['cent'] = cent

    result += '.'
    return gettext(result, **params)
```

I know that `pybabel` won't extract the dynamic string, so I put this into the `en.po`, `de.po`, `zh.po` etc. files

```
msgid "Buying this will cost you %(usd) USD."
msgstr ""

msgid "Buying this will cost you %(cent) cent."
msgstr ""

msgid "Buying this will cost you %(usd) USD and %(cent) cent."
msgstr ""
```

But when I run

```
pybabel update -i messages.pot -d translations --previous
```

It put my precious `msgid` parts into comments with `#~`!

Could you help me to find a better way to handle this specific usecase? Many thanks and hugs in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

po catalog entry:

```
msgid = 'Buying this will cost you %s USD'
```

python:

```
result += {{ _("Buying this will cost you (%s) USD" % usd) }}
```